# infinite length of a curve

Tags: curves

I need to show that

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
\sin(1/x),& x \neq 0 \\
0,& x = 0\end{cases}$$

on $[0,1]$ has an infinite arc length.

I've tried to prove that $(f'(x))^2$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$.

I also tried to use the fact that it's not uniformly continuous (maybe it's not relevant).

Thank you.

Comment: It does not suffice that $(f'(x))^2$ is unbounded. For instance $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ also has an unbounded $(g'(x))^2$ on [0,1], but it still has a finite arc length. Similarly uniform continuity is not relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The function is not continuous at $0$, so it isn't even a curve on $[0,1]$.

It *is* a curve with infinite length on $(0,1]$. The simplest way to see this is probably to notice that the curve length between each maximum and the neighboring minimum must be at least $2$. Since there are infinitely many wiggles and each of them contributes a curve length of at least $2$ ...

Answer (score 0):

We can find a lower bound on the length of the curve by approximating it with straight lines. For every natural number $n$ the point
$$
p_n=\Big(\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\,\pi},(-1)^n\Big)
$$
lies on the curve. And the distance between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ is at least $2$. That's enough to do it!